# How are reserved slots re-allocated between reservation/projects if idle slots are used?

Tags: google-bigquery

The documentation on [Introduction to Reservations: Idle Slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro#idle_slots) states that idle slots from reservations can be used by other reservations if required

> By default, queries running in a reservation automatically use idle slots from other reservations. That means a job can always run as long as there's capacity. Idle capacity is immediately preemptible back to the original assigned reservation as needed, regardless of the priority of the query that needs the resources. This happens automatically in real time.

However, I'm wondering if this can have a negative effect on other reservations in a scenario where idle slots are used but are shortly after required by the "owning" reservation.

To be concrete I would like to understand if i can regard assigned slots as **guarantee** OR as a **best effort**.

**Example:**

---

- Reserved slots: 100
- Reservation A: 50 Slots
- Reservation B: 50 Slots

"A" starts a query at 14:00:00 and the computation takes 300 seconds if 100 slots are used.
All slots are idle at the start of the query, thus all 100 slots are made available to A.

5 seconds later at 14:00:05 "B" starts a query that takes 30 seconds if 50 slots are used.

*Note*:

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that both queries have only excactly 1 stage and each computation unit ("job") in the stage takes the full time of the query. I.e. the stage is divided into 100 jobs and if a slot starts the computation it takes the full 300 seconds to finish successfully.

I'm fairly certain that on "multiple stages" or "shorter computation times" (e.g. if the computation can be broken down in 1000 jobs) GBQ would be smart enough to dynamically re-assign the freed up slot the reservation it belongs to.

---

**Questions:**

- does "B" now have to wait until a slot in "A" finishes?

  - this would mean ~5 min waiting time

    - I'm not sure how "realistic" the 5 min are, but I feel this is an important variable since I wouldn't worry about a couple of seconds - but I would worry about a couple of minutes!
- or might an already started computation of "A" also be killed mid-flight?

  - the docu [Introduction to Reservations: Slot Scheduling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro#slot_scheduling) seems to suggest something like this

    > The goal of the scheduler is to find a medium between being too aggressive with evicting running tasks (which results in wasting slot time) and being too lenient (which results in jobs with long running tasks getting a disproportionate share of the slot time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer via [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/n1padd/how_are_reserved_slots_reallocated_between/gwi8q2k/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> A stage may run for quite some time (minutes, even hours in really bad cases) but a stage is run by many workers. And most workers complete their work within a very short time, e.g. milliseconds or seconds. Hence rebalancing, I.e. reallocating slots from one job to another is very fast.
>
> So if a rebalancing happens and a job loses a large part of slots, then it will run a lot slower. And the one that gains slots will run fast. And this change is quick.
>
> So in the above example. As job B starts 5 seconds in, within a second or so it would have acquired most of its slots.

So bottom line:

- a query is broken up into "a lot" of units of work
- each unit of work finishes pretty fast
- this give GBQ to opportunity to re-assign slots